# Trouble using glment’s LASSO regression on sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, glmnet, lasso-regression

Hi Stack Overflow Community,

I'm encountering some difficulties while attempting to use `glmnet` in R to perform LASSO regression with bootstrapped data. I've successfully executed the code provided below to conduct ridge regression on the same dataset. However, when I try to implement LASSO regression using `glmnet`, I receive the following cryptic error:

*Error in intI(j, n = x@Dim[2], dn[[2]], give.dn = FALSE): 'NA' indices are not (yet?) supported   for sparse Matrices*

So far, I've checked the data for any NA values, but there are none in the relevant DataFrame.

Here is the relevant code to assist with debugging. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

———————————————————————————————————————---------------------

Data description: Each row of the data describes an individual. The response variable is indicated by either 0 or 1, and the predictors consist of a combination of continuous and discrete values.

**(Splitting 70/30 training-testing data in predictor and response variables)**

```
    split.70 <- sample(nrow(data), nrow(data) * 0.7, replace = FALSE) 
    train.70 <- data[split.70,]
    test.70 <- data[-split.70,]

    data <- na.omit(data)
    response <- data$response.variable
    predictors <- model.matrix(response.variable ~., data = data)

    ridge.lasso.train.70.predictors <- predictors[split.70,]
    ridge.lasso.train.70.response <- response[split.70]
  
    ridge.lasso.test.70.predictors <- predictors[-split.70,]
    ridge.lasso.test.70.response <- response[-split.70]

**(Running LASSO regression 100 times on bootstrapped data)**

    for (i in 1:100){
  
      boot.rows.LASSO70 <- sample(x = 1:number.rows, number.rows, replace = TRUE)
  
      boot.data.LASSO70.predictors <-ridge.lasso.train.70.predictors[boot.rows.LASSO70,]
      boot.data.LASSO70.recidivate <- ridge.lasso.train.70.response[boot.rows.LASSO70]
  
      lambda.70.train.accuracy <- rep(NA, 100)
      lambda.70.test.accuracy <- rep(NA, 100)
  
      for (j in 1:100){

        LASSO.70.mdl <- glmnet(x = boot.data.LASSO70.predictors, y = boot.data.LASSO70.response,
                           alpha = 1, 
                           family = "binomial")
    
        LASSO.70.train.predict <- predict(LASSO.70.mdl, newx = boot.data.LASSO70.predictors,
                                      type = "response", s = LASSO.70.mdl$lambda[j])
    
        LASSO.70.test.predict <- predict(LASSO.70.mdl, newx = ridge.lasso.test.70.predictors, 
                                     type = "response", s = LASSO.70.mdl$lambda[j])
}}
```